# Replacing a string unless it contains a given substring with sed

Tags: regex, unix, sed, text-processing

I have a file which contains many links of the form `<a href="foo">`. These need to be given a `.html` extension, and I have the following command to do so:

```
sed -i 's/\(href="\)\([^"]*\)/\1\2.html/g' "$FILE"
```

However, I need to *not* do this on any link which has either a protocol (e.g. `https://` or already has an extension (e.g. `.css`, `.js`—happy to match only these specifically.

How can I do this? Is sed still an appropriate tool here?

Comment: I imagine you got downvoted because you did not provide a minimal, reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This `sed` may work.

```
$ sed -Ei.bak '/https|\.[a-z]+/!s/"[^"]*/&.html/' input_file
```

If not, please consider adding more information to the question.

Comment: With the addition of an href to not catch other strings, this is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -F "<|>" 
         '/a href=\"https/ { 
                             for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) { 
                                                  if (match($i,"a href=\"https")) { 
                                                            split($i,arr,"\"");
                                                            if (!match(arr[2],".")) { 
                                                               sub(arr[2],arr[2]".html",$0) 
                                                            } 
                                                  } 
                                                 } 
                            }1' inputfile > inputfile1
```

Using awk as an alternative, set the file delimiter to "<" or ">" and then search for all lines that contain 'a href="https' (This will discount http entries)

Loop through all the fields based on the delimiters.

If the field contains 'a href="https', process the field. Split the field into the array **arr** based on the delimiter '"' The entry arr[2] will therefore contain the href entry i.e **foo**

Processing foo, if the entry doesn't have a "." (checked using awk's match function), substitute arr[2] for arr[2] with ".html" appended to the end (using awk's sub function). Use 1 to print the changes to the line.

The changes will be output to inputfile1

Once you have verified that the changes are correct:

```
mv inputfile1 inputfile
```